# How to work with more than 7 CALayers?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

Sorry for my English; I'll try to be clear.

I'm preparing a long animation. It's loaded in `viewDidLoad`. each `CALayer` is related with a `CABasicAnimation` and all the `CALayer`s are sublayers of `self.view.layer`. When it arrives at the 8th layer it doesn't appear anymore on the screen! Is there a maximum number of sublayers for a layer? Why doesn't the 8th layer appear on the simulator?

Comment: there was an error. it was missing the .cgiimage after the seventh image. so everything is solved. thanks everybody. this post can be deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a maximum number of sublayers specified, and if there is a maximum it is certainly much much larger than 8.

Comment: so, why doesn't appear the 8th layer on the screen? i did the same procedure as the other ones. thanks for the fast answer

Comment: @user1643728: Don't post your code in the comments, post your code in the question.